# What setting of clang-format (12.0.1) will not add a space between the R prefix and a raw string in C++?

Tags: c++, clang-format, rawstring

What is the option for clang-format 12 (12.0.1) that puts a space between the R prefix and a raw string:

```
std::string str = R"(raw string)";
```

vs

```
std::string str = R "(raw string)";
```

The latter is not accepted by gcc (9.3.0) or the clang being used by VSCode 1.62.3, so this actually breaks the source file/build.

My .clang-format file setting causes the space, and the built-in gnu preset does as well. None of the other presets (llvm, google, chromium, microsoft, mozilla, or webkit) cause this.

I have done a dump of all the formats and compared them setting by setting. I first eliminated all settings in my configuration that matched one of the presets that did not cause this. Then I eliminated any remaining setting that was the same between the gnu preset and a preset that did not add the space. Finally, I went through each of the few remaining settings and changed the settings in my .clang-format file to values in the working presets to see if they fixed the issue, but they did not.

Doing this, I seem to have eliminated all of the settings as the cause.

Before I spend more time, hours digging through the actual source code, I'm hoping someone may have some insight into this and be able to point me at the setting that is causing the issue.

For reference, I am including my .clang-format setting file below. But as noted the gnu preset also exhibits this behavior.

Thanks for any help.

```
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: None
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: None
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: None
AlignConsecutiveMacros: None
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 80
CommentPragmas: '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '^<ext/.*\.h>'
    Priority: 2
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority: 1
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: '^<.*'
    Priority: 2
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
  - Regex: '.*'
    Priority: 3
    SortPriority: 0
    CaseSensitive: false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '([-_](test|unittest))?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentRequires: false
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
Language: Cpp
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd: ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Never
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
RawStringFormats:
  - Language: Cpp
    Delimiters:
      - cc
      - CC
      - cpp
      - Cpp
      - CPP
      - 'c++'
      - 'C++'
      - 'cxx'
    CanonicalDelimiter: ''
    BasedOnStyle: google
  - Language: TextProto
    Delimiters:
      - pb
      - PB
      - proto
      - PROTO
    EnclosingFunctions:
      - EqualsProto
      - EquivToProto
      - PARSE_PARTIAL_TEXT_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEST_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEXT_PROTO
      - ParseTextOrDie
      - ParseTextProtoOrDie
      - ParseTestProto
      - ParsePartialTestProto
    CanonicalDelimiter: ''
    BasedOnStyle: google
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: true
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: C++03
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth: 4
UseCRLF: false
UseTab: Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
```

EDIT: ============================================================

In reference to @Ted Lyngmo's comment, here is a test input and the outputs:

Original: (note both space & no space are provided)

```
std::string foo()
{
    std::string str1 = R"(raw string 1)";
    std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

my .clang-format:

```
std::string foo()
{
    std::string str1 = R "(raw string 1)";
    std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

gnu:

```
std::string
foo ()
{
  std::string str1 = R "(raw string 1)";
  std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
  return str1 + str2;
}
```

llvm, google, chromium: (note that original is left alone as @Ted Lyngmo mentions)

```
std::string foo() {
  std::string str1 = R"(raw string 1)";
  std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
  return str1 + str2;
}
```

microsoft, webkit: (note original left alone)

```
std::string foo()
{
    std::string str1 = R"(raw string 1)";
    std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

mozilla: (note original left alone)

```
std::string
foo()
{
  std::string str1 = R"(raw string 1)";
  std::string str2 = R "(raw string 1)";
  return str1 + str2;
}
```

This is interesting. I don't see any of the settings removing the space, but mine and gnu add the space. That seems like good info, but I still need to know what setting will leave the format alone and not add the space, so I can modify my own configuration.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's clang-format that does it? I have 12.0.1 too and I used your format file but it didn't change whatever I had there. `R "` stayed at `R "` and `R"` stayed at `R"`.

Comment: Does clang-format 13.0.0 also have the problem?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thank you for the question. I've updated the question with my findings.

Comment: @Eljay, yes 13.0.0 appears to behave the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, with @TedLyngmo's help, I believe I found the setting.

`Standard: C++03` causes the space to be added. `Standard: Auto` or `Standard: C++11` leaves the format as in the source.

For my own preference, I would prefer to set `Standard` to `C++03` so that clang-format will add (and not remove) the space between the trailing angle brackets of compound templates.

It kind of stinks that those two things are connected.

Comment: Ahh, good find.  Makes sense that `C++03` would have both of those behaviors.

Comment: @Eljay, why would C++03 want a space between a prefix and a string? From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal , it appears that wide string literals (`L"str"`) were available from the start. But adding a space between the prefix and the string doesn't compile for that type of string literal either. Was this ever acceptable? (And doesn't it make the C++03 & gnu settings invalid?)

Comment: Because in C++03, it's not a string literal prefix.

Comment: Nice! You found it! Clang format has a description about what what they aim for. It's not "total perfection for everyone" ... which is obvious for me since I really don't understand some of their rules at all. I have to fix them myself to make the formatting proper.

Comment: raw string literal is a new feature in C++11. Try the `u8`, `u` and `U` prefixes and I believe you'll also see the same behavior. In fact when C++11 added user-defined literals it also broke many code which was written without spaces in macros because those was mistreated as suffixes

Comment: I just don't understand why the C++03 setting would touch any prefix it doesn't recognize (as a C++03 or earlier construct). It should just leave these alone and only adjust for those it knows (L, u8, u, U, etc.). Oddly, the other Standard settings (presumably) *do* recognize these later string literal decorations, yet they leave them as-is. (Of course, I wouldn't care if I didn't want the compound template closing angle brackets to be separated, and that setting was distinct from the string literal prefix adjustment.)